# R stops working and arrows disappearing with prime check function

Tags: r, function, nested-loops

```
prime <- function(number){
    if (number!=2){
        for (num in 1:number){
            while ((number%%num)==0){
                counter <- 0
                counter <- counter+1
                
            }
        }
        return((counter-2)==0)
    }else{
        FALSE
    }
}
```

My function was designed for prime test, prime numbers only divided by itself and 1. So I've looped all the numbers from 1 to n(number itself) and counted the number of the 0 remainder divisions. Result must be 2 (n/n and n/1 remainders are 0) so (counter-2)==0 returns TRUE if the number is the prime number. Only exception is 2. But my code doesn't working also stops the RStudio. Code line arrows disappearing, R stops return any value.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a loop for this. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the line arrow disappears, but this code works for me:

```r
is.prime <- function(x){
  if( x == 2) return(TRUE)
  sum(x %% 1:x  == 0) == 2
}

is.prime(2)
#> [1] TRUE

is.prime(10)
#> [1] FALSE

is.prime(11)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: 2 is not prime?

Comment: hmm.. no... just kidding. My mistake. I'll edit now. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I'm not going to lie @JonSpring, I had to google if 2 was prime. I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't know that.

Comment: I think people find it counterintuitive that 2 is prime because we learn early about even & odd numbers, and all the other even numbers are non-prime. Something clicked for me when I realized we could have words for numbers if they're divisible by 3 ("is it threeven or throdd"?) and in that case all the "threeven" numbers except 3 would be nonprime, as well. And so on for multiples of all the other primes.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 problems with your code:

1. You are arbitrarily defining 2 as being non-prime. It is prime and there is no reason to treat it as a special case.
2. You are constantly resetting `counter` to 0. It should be initialized just once outside of the `for` loop
3. Your `while` loop is an infinite loop. If `(number%%num)==0` then nothing in the body of the loop will make that false. This causes the loop to be an infinite loop, which is why RStudio hangs when you run your code. The fix is to change this loop into something which is not a loop at all -- it is really an `if` statement that you need.

There was another thing which isn't incorrect but is somewhat awkward: using `(counter - 2) == 0` to test if `counter == 2`.

Fixing these problems leads to the following code:

```
prime <- function(number) {
  counter <- 0
  for (num in 1:number) {
    if ((number %% num) == 0) {
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
  counter == 2
}
```

This succeeds in correctly testing for primes. Note that it is an extremely inefficient test. Your test would use 1,000,000 remainder operations to classify 1,000,000 as nonprime when surely one operation would suffice -- just divide by 2. To make it more efficient you could exploit the fact that a number is either prime or it is divisible by a number no bigger than its square root. For an odd number, you can test if it is prime by checking if it has an odd divisor less that or equal to its square root. This would allow you to check if a number in the vicinity of 1,000,000 is prime with at most 500 remainder operations rather than the 1,000,000 that your approach would use.